# Regular expression to extract unique fields from .sdf file in R

Tags: r, regex, string, chemistry

I am on the lookout for a regular expression in R to extract the fields given in an .sdf chemical data file.
The fields in this case are delimited by < > and follow a ">  " at the start of a line.
E.g. in the case of

```
string=">  <FIELD1>\nfield text1\n\n>  <FIELD2>\nfield text2\n\n>  <FIELD3>field text3"
```

it would have to return

```
fields=c("FIELD1","FIELD2","FIELD3")
```

(they could occur multiple times, so I would need only the `unique()` ones)
Any thoughts?

cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.  It extracts the portion of the string matched by the part of the regular expression surrounded by parentheses and then simplifies it using `unique`:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(string, "<([^>]*)>", simplify = unique)
```

giving:

```
[1] "FIELD1" "FIELD2" "FIELD3"
```

*REVISED* minor simplification.

Comment: Ha many thanks! And also for the other answer which also works perfectly! :-) Thx millions!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gregexpr` and `regmatches` to extract the substrings and `unique` to remove duplicates.

```
unique(regmatches(string, gregexpr("(?<=<)\\w+(?=>)", string, perl = TRUE))[[1]])
# [1] "FIELD1" "FIELD2" "FIELD3"
```